# User not found using IdentityServerV3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

Ok, so this one has been highly frustrating and I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

So if I may give a run down of the architecture:

**Solution**

- IdentityServer Layer
- WebApi Layer
- MVC layer (as the client)

**The Issue**

When trying to access the user that has been authenticated by the IdentityServer it always returns `false`

```
if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   var identity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
   foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
   {
     Debug.Write(claim.Type + " " + claim.Value);
   }
}
```

I've spent many hours trying to figure why I do not have access to the user.

**IdentityServer**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp => 
    {
        var idServerServiceFactory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
        .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
        .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
        .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get());

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            Factory = idServerServiceFactory,
            SiteName = "Proderty Security Token Service",
            IssuerUri = "https://localhost:44300/identity",
            PublicOrigin = "https://localhost:44300/",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate()
        };

        idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
    });
}

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client()
            {
                ClientId = "prodertyclientcredentials",
                ClientName = "Proderty (Client Credentials)",
                Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                {
                    new Secret("Some Secret here".Sha256())
                },
                AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
            },
            new Client()
            {
                ClientId = "prodertyauthcode",
                ClientName = "Proderty (Authorization Code)",
                Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCode,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                {
                    "http://localhost:10765/prodertycallback"
                },
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                {
                    new Secret("Some Secret here".Sha256())
                },
                AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
            },
            new Client()
            {
                ClientId = "prodertyhybrid",
                ClientName = "Proderty (Hybrid)",
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                {
                    "http://localhost:10765"
                },
                AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
            }
        };
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new List<Scope>()
        {
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "prodertymanagment",
                DisplayName = "Proderty Management",
                Description = "Allow the application to manage proderty on your behalf.",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource
            },
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile
        };
    }
        return new List<InMemoryUser>()
        {
            new InMemoryUser()
            {
                Username = "Terry",
                Password = "Bob",
                Subject = "b053d546-6ca8-b95c-77e94d705ddf",
                Claims = new[] 
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Terry"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Wingfield")
                }
            },
            new InMemoryUser()
            {
                Username = "John",
                Password = "Bob",
                Subject = "bb61e881-3a49-8b62-c13dbe102018",
                Claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "John"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Borris")
                }
            }
        };
```

As you can see the IdentityServer seems positively intact. Once called I expect that I should be access the user on the MVC client.

**WebApi**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
        new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44300/identity",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "prodertymanagment" }
        });
```

}

```
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public string GetOne()
    {
        return "If you can see this, then we must be authorized! - GETONE - Coming From Test Controller";
    }}
}
```

**MVCClient**

```
public static HttpClient GetClient()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var accessToken = Token.RequestAccessTokenAuthorizationCode();
    if (accessToken != null)
    {
        client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    }

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44301/");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
     new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


    return client;
}
    public static string RequestAccessTokenAuthorizationCode()
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("ProdertyCookie");
        if (cookie != null && cookie["access_token"] != null)
        {
            return cookie["access_token"];
        }

        var authorizeRequest = new IdentityModel.Client.AuthorizeRequest(
            "https://localhost:44300/identity/connect/authorize"
            );

        var state = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;

        var url = authorizeRequest.CreateAuthorizeUrl(
            "prodertyauthcode",
            "code",
            "prodertymanagment",
            "http://localhost:10765/prodertycallback",
            state);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
        return null;
    }
    // GET: ProdertyCallback
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var authCode = Request.QueryString["code"];

        var client = new TokenClient(
            "https://localhost:44300/identity/connect/token",
            "prodertyauthcode",
            "Some Secret here"
            );

        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
            authCode,
            "http://localhost:10765/prodertycallback"
            );

        Response.Cookies["ProdertyCookie"]["access_token"] = tokenResponse.AccessToken;

        return Redirect(Request.QueryString["state"]);
    }
```

With the code above everything works, If not logged in I'm pushed to the IdentityServer login page, My callback fires and then returned to the originating page. I also have a access token.

Now that I'm authorized to access the page, I expect to have access to the user but I don't which is highly frustrating.

I'm very aware that it's the app that's being authenticated but I'm sure the purpose was to access the user that authenticated the app (As a user of the client system too).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{

    if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var identity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
        {
            Debug.Write(claim.Type + " " + claim.Value);
        }
    }

    var httpClient = ProdertyHttpClient.GetClient();
    var test = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/test/getone").ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (test.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringContent = await test.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Content(stringContent);
    }
    else
    {

        return Content(ExceptionHelper.GetExceptionFromResponse(test).ToString());
    }


}
```

The only thing that springs to mind is using the `Authorize Attribute` which attempts to use the core `asp.net identity model` which I have not install because I'll have a custom data store.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't follow why some of the code is done the way it is. Do the IdentityServer samples work for you? It might be best to copy those and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi @BrockAllen a pleasure to have your comment! The code is very similar to a PluralSight course by Kevin Dockx... Iv'e spent many hours trying to understand IdentityServer as I was fed up off using Forms Authentication and wanted to learn something new. I have solved the issue and shall post an update soon. In the meantime, If the code is not to the appropriate standard and best usage, a subtle request to the author to review his course, may help future devs.